# Process.Start in BackgroundWorker

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to start a new process when BackgroundWorker IsBusy.

**Global.asax:**

```
BackgroundWorker thread;
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StartThread();
}
protected void StartThread()
{
     thread = new BackgroundWorker();
     thread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
     thread.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     Process p = new Process();
     p.StartInfo.FileName = "exe.exe";
     p.Start();
     p.WaitForExit(10000);
}
```

But nothing was happened. Also there was no exceptions raised. 
I've inserted a breakpoint at the p.Start() line. All works fine except that the process didn't started.

What could be the reason of this?
Also I've tried to use Thread class for this but I've got the same result.

Comment: You should check the `bool` result of the [`Process.Start()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: The result of Process.Start() equals TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new thread from inside the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` delegate. When you fire off the `DoWork` event, why not start the new process from the UI thread. This would be much better in terms of thread safty and concurrency - this could also be the root cause of you problem.

Comment: The process i want to start must work on the server all the time.